# CakePHP doesn't create tests tables

Tags: php, cakephp, testing

I've tried to do some tests, but cakephp doesn't create de test_{tablename} tables! He is trying to use de original tables.
Database config:

```
var $test = array(

        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        'login' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'tests_clubpets',
        'encoding' => 'utf8'
);
```

Fixture:

```
class AdminFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    var $name = 'Admin';

    var $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'null' => false, 'default' => NULL, 'key' => 'primary'),
        ...
        'tableParameters' => array('charset' => 'utf8', 'collate' => 'utf8_general_ci', 'engine' => 'InnoDB')
    );

    var $records = array(
        array(
            'id' => 1,
            'nome' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
            ...
    );
}
```

Model:

```
class AdminTestCase extends CakeTestCase {
    var $fixtures = array('app.admin');

    function startTest() {
        $this->Admin =& ClassRegistry::init('Admin');
    }

    function endTest() {
        unset($this->Admin);
        ClassRegistry::flush();
    }

}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when you create the $test database connection, cake should be trying to make the tables in that database. according to your code that should be in `tests_clubpets`. make sure the database is created and that the user has permissions on the table. also check you did not make any typeo's

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have your tables named test_{tablename}, use:

```
'prefix' => 'test_',
```